# Can I upload data to Azure Blob Storage with encryption and use OPENROWSET API to import it?

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-blob-storage, openrowset

I want to upload encrypted data to azure blob storage and import it to azure database.
One way is to encrypt data before uploading it to azure blob store and import data using openrowset and then decrypt it. Is there any other method to do it ?

Comment: May I know from where you are uploading data to azure blob storage?